# H2 User defined aggregate function, ListAgg, can't use DISTINCT or TRIM() on the first parameter

Tags: java, sql, h2

So I have a DB2 production database in which I need to use the available function ListAgg. I would like my unit test, which is using H2, to correctly test this functionality. Unfortunately H2 does not support ListAgg directly. I can, however, create a user defined aggregate function...

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.h2.api.AggregateFunction;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;

public class ListAgg implements AggregateFunction
{

private List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
private String delimiter = ",";

@Override
public void init(Connection conn) throws SQLException
{
}

@Override
public int getType(int[] inputTypes) throws SQLException
{
    if (inputTypes.length != 2) {
        throw new java.sql.SQLException("The aggregate function ListAgg must have 2 arguments.");
    }
    return java.sql.Types.VARCHAR;
}

@Override
public void add(Object sqlValues) throws SQLException
{
    Object[] objects = (Object[]) sqlValues;
    this.delimiter = (String) objects[1];
    String value = (String) objects[0];
    values.add(value);
}

@Override
public Object getResult() throws SQLException
{
    return Joiner.on(delimiter).join(values);
}

}
```

Which I have done. This works just fine for

```
ListAgg(columnName, ',')
```

But fails for

```
ListAgg(DISTINCT TRIM(columnName), ',')
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:
I get the following error message:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback;
bad SQL grammar [select ..., LISTAGG(DISTINCT TRIM(columnName), ',') as 
columnName_LIST, from ... group by ...]; nested exception is 
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT ... "; 
expected "NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, SELECT, FROM"; SQL statement:
select ... from ... group by ... [42001-174]    
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231) 
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
```

EDIT2:

Does `COUNT()` also implement AggregateFunction or is it using something else internally? Because H2 is able to handle `COUNT(DISTINCT columnName)`

Comment: As of Version 1.4.198 (2019-02-22), H2 has an implementation of LISTAGG - see [changelog](http://www.h2database.com/html/changelog.html). It's described as "partial" but the examples in the docs at least include `LISTAGG(NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID)` and `LISTAGG(ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) OVER (ORDER BY ID)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think H2 allows you to use the `DISTINCT` keyword on your custom aggregate functions. But you can easily define your own "distinct" version of `ListAgg`:

```
public class DistinctListAgg implements AggregateFunction {
    private Set<String> values = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    // The rest is the same
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I appreciate the insight on how to get a distinct version. But I want to be able to test without changing code between environments. In this case, I would be running ListAgg( DISTINCT TRIM(columnName)) in production and [Distinct]ListAgg(columnName) for the unit test.

Comment: Hmm, does [DB2's `LISTAGG`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0058709.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-4-0-7) really support `DISTINCT`? Is that an undocumented feature?

Anyway, I suspect that you'll encounter these kinds of differences time and again when you're not integration-testing on DB2, directly

Comment: Is it really that surprising that `LISTAGG` supports `DISTINCT`? `COUNT` and `SUM` are (DB2) aggregate functions that support it as well.

Comment: Well, it isn't documented, and Oracle's `LISTAGG` doesn't support it, unfortunately.