# H2 User defined ListAgg function using 'WITHIN GROUP'

Tags: java, sql, h2, listagg

Thanks to a question here on stackoverflow I defined a custom ListAgg aggregate function for my H2 DB which seems to work fine.

But my SQL statement using the ListAgg function looks something like this:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(SOMECOLUMN, ';')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SOMECOLUMN)
FROM SOMETABLE
WHERE SOMECOLUMN = 'someValue';
```

And fails with 'Syntax error: expected "BY"'.
Probably because he does not understand the 'WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SOMECOLUMN)' expression and expects a 'BY' after the 'GROUP'?!

Is it possible to teach him this too?

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in `GROUP_CONCAT()` http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#group_concat

Comment: horse with no name: We are using Oracle in production (which does not know group_concat) and just want to be able to run our tests against H2 Database

Comment: It's a bad idea to test with a different DBMS then you use in production. And this is just one example why that is the case

Comment: horse with no name: You're right, but this setup is not under consideration atm/yet in our environment

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution updating the version of h2 database to the latest.

Thanks to a comment on this answer: [H2 User defined aggregate function, ListAgg, can't use DISTINCT or TRIM() on the first parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047121/h2-user-defined-aggregate-function-listagg-cant-use-distinct-or-trim-on-the)

> As of Version 1.4.198 (2019-02-22), H2 has an implementation of
> LISTAGG - see [changelog](http://www.h2database.com/html/changelog.html). It's described as "partial" but the examples
> in the docs at least include LISTAGG(NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER
> BY ID) and LISTAGG(ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) OVER (ORDER BY
> ID) – Andrew Spencer Jun 21 '19 at 13:13